# How to pass Cognito Identity to Lambda when using AWSSignInManager

Tags: ios, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

If you are using the AWSSignInManager and AWSAuthUI how do you ensure that the cognito identity is passed to Lambda calls when using AWSLambdaInvoker?  I am currently using the following to setup my defaultServiceConfiguration

```
let credentialProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: .USEast1, identityPoolId: "YourIdentityPoolId")
let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USEast1, credentialsProvider: credentialProvider)
AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
```

After utilizing the above code, I can make calls to Lambda functions but it doesn't appear to be automatically passing on the correct identity id for cognito once a user authenticates via AWSAuthUI.  Is there something I need to set with this newly authenticated identity on the defaultServicConfiguration upon a successful login?